# SharePoint 2019 on premise Modern Library +New shows NO documents

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

New modern library on premise 2019.  Only "Folder" and "Link" show up under +New.  We don't have OOS and don't want it installed in the farm.

Is this expected behavior?  We have to go to Classic Experience and create New Document from the toolbar.

Any ideas?  HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without Office Online Server, this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I did tests in my environment, and without OOS installed in SharePoint 2019, modern library can't create documents under "New".

If you don't want to switch to classic mode every time, I suggest you install OOS.

If you need more information, you can go to [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration) and post about it.